# EF 4 SaveChanges() Not Working For ONLY one entity, Profiler shows no db call. Broken datalink context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I am adding a new db object and all is going well till I write the update. SaveChanges() is not doing anything for the new object (works just fine for all the other objects). It is not throwing an error and sql profiler shows it never makes a call to the db.

So I'm in water that is a little over my head. Something must be broken (duh!!) with the entity context or similar?

I would post code but I don't know what to post? I need some help / direction in more advanced diagnostics than what I have done to this point to dig deeper.

Thank You

---

Edit here is the insert and save code

```
 _forumExternalRepository.Update(ExtForumSub);
```

which is:

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
        try
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            this._context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            //removed for brevity
        }

    }
```

Now I think you have helped me get another clue. Running the code through and stopping on the first line I am paying attention to something I didn't think mattered before. When I update an address (which works) I have:

```
[System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Address_5B8E6B67495BDEB98C96C6BBCB504F9D6E1382361D18BC0790EBF9B82A3A6415] = {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Address_5B8E6B67495BDEB98C96C6BBCB504F9D6E1382361D18BC0790EBF9B82A3A6415}
```

But when I send my object to be updated I don't have this system.Data.Entity object attached.

So if this is part of the problem great...but I still don't know exactly how to get it attached to my object as I am doing the same steps for address??

Comment: You should post the code where your inserting the entity and saving it to the DB or it's difficult to give specific help with what is wrong in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be obvious but are you making a call to add the object to the context?  Something like:

```
context.Users.Add(obj);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Uhh yeah so as Tommy said in Tommy Boy. I'm a retard. I wasn't adding it to the larger object so it wasn't getting added to the entity context.